# Is there any neater way to reuse the result from/within the bool test of a ternary, as an output of the ternary?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a collection where some shapes may be blue. If there are blue shapes, I want to return a count of blue shapes. If there are no blue shapes I want to return a count of all shapes. This is being done in an initializer, and also the counting for blue shapes is long and ugly:

```
new SomeObject {
  CountOf = someCollection.Shapes.Count(s => s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue") > 0 ? 
    (someCollection.Shapes.Count(s => s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue") :
    someCollection.Shapes.Count()
}
```

..this is even longer, and uglier, and counts twice. It could be optimized some by making it Any rather than Count, but let's assume I know that most of the time there will be blue shapes near the end, so looping for the Any+Count is nearly as much a resource burn as looping for the count, and it'll still be ugly

I can re-use the count like this:

```
int c;
new SomeObject {
  CountOf = (c = someCollection.Shapes.Count(s => s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue")) > 0 ? 
    c :
    someCollection.Shapes.Count()
}
```

..this relying on the assignment to `c` returning the value assigned, and doing the bool test on it, and then we can use `c` in the output. There isn't a way I know of to declare `c` inline to the ternary though. (And it still might count twice)

It's not possible to use the being-initialized property as temporary store within the ternary, nor init it twice (though it could be inited to the count of blue and then tested after creation and changed if 0) and C# doesn't have any truthy behavior like javascript that could be leveraged to pick `b` in `a||b` if `a` was 0..

Is there any trick I'm missing to neaten up and optimize ternaries of the form `somevalue_test : somevalue : othervalue` such as this count, or even simpler ones such as `some.Long.Chain.To.A.String.Length > 100 ? some.Long.Chain.To.A.String.Remove(100) : some.Long.Chain.To.A.String`?

<sub>Definition: "neat" - single line, not [predominantly] repeating code, or some truthy/falsy style alternative</sub>

Comment: Thought just occurred, now I've written all that out, perhaps creating a bool local function that returns the count via an `out` param that can be used in the ternary..

Comment: Do you realize that you're evaluating `someCollection.Shapes.Count(s => s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue")` twice?

Comment: @JHBonarius: Yes, that's basically the point of the question - working out how to avoid that.

Comment: There may be a more LinQ for that. CountBy will return the count of blue and not blue. you can perhaps get it's result in a nammed tuple `var (countBlue, countOther) = ...`

Answer (score 6):

I'd either just use a local variable (which means it can't be part of an object initializer, but sometimes that's just the way of things) or write an extension method:

```cs
// TODO: Rename!
public static int CountIfAnyOrAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int totalCount = 0;
    int matchingCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        totalCount++;
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            matchingCount++;
        }
    }
    return matchingCount == 0 ? totalCount : matchingCount;
}
```

Note that this ensures that you only iterate over the sequence once, which is useful if even `Count()` is expensive, or if iterating over the sequence multiple times might given inconsistent results.

Answer (score 4):

simply don't inline everything (also improves readability IMHO)

```cs
var blueColorCount = someCollection.Shapes.Count(s => s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue");

new SomeObject {
  CountOf = blueColorCount > 0 ? blueColorCount : someCollection.Shapes.Count()
}
```

edit:
ok, was more to the question then I realized. The extention method by Jon Skeet could work, but may be overly generalistic if not used anywhere else. Other solution is to use local counters.

```cs
var blueColorCount = 0;
var totalCount = someCollection.Shapes.Select(s =>
{
    if (s.Attributes.First(a => a.Name == "Color").Value == "Blue") blueColorCount++;
    return true; // just any value, unused.
}).Count();

new SomeObject {
  CountOf = blueColorCount > 0 ? blueColorCount : totalCount
}
```